# using cell references in links excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have to aggregate data from multiple excel files into one. In my aggregate file, I have created a column with the names of the files from which I want to collect the data. In each respective row, I have to compile values from specific cells of the "origin" file. How can I construct my formulas?

Example:

I have a file `AGGREGATE.xlsx`, in which column `A` reads `AL`, `AND` etc.

in cell `B3`, I have to insert the value of cell `C11` from the file `AL.xlsx`

in cell `B4`, I have to insert the value of cell `C11` from the file `AND.xlsx`

and so on.

Is there a way to construct my formula as

```
=[filename.xlsx]!Sheet1!C11
```

but where the "filename" is variable and refers to the cells in my aggregate workbook instead of specifying "fixed" file names? So that I don't have to change the formula for each line and can just copy/paste for the whole table.

Sorry I tried to attach an image to make it more clear but I'm a newbie here and don't have the necessary "reputation" points.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read the filename from cell `A3`, then this would go in cell `B3`:

`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",A3,".xlsx]Sheet1!C11"))`

Basically, you are building a string using the value in column A, then using the `INDIRECT` formula to reference the value of the indicated cell. The only problem is the workbooks need to be open for this formula to work. You can read about the technique [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html#RefWkbk).

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, click on the check mark beside this answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in so that others will know that the question has been resolved.